# Merge url with parameters into 1 in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I am creating a dashboard for our service. And I want to create metrics for url requests.
Lets say have a similar url like this one:

```
/api/v1/users/{userId}/settings
```

And I have following query in Splunk

```
url=*/api/v1/users/*/settings 
| stats avg(timeTaken) as avg_latency, p99(timeTaken) as "p99(ms)", perc75(timeTaken) as "p75(ms)", count  as total_requests, count(eval(responseStatus=500)) as failed_requests by url 
| eval "success_rate"=round((total_requests - failed_requests)/total_requests*100,2) 
| eval avg = round(avg) 
| sort success_rate
```

All I want is to have a table with one common url showing all the metrics. But instead, I get a table with a list of all urls with different parameters.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a field which is the URL minus the UserId part, And therefore the stats will be grouped by which url is called.

You can do this by using `split(url,"/")` to make a mv field of the url, and take out the UserId by one of two ways depending on the URLs.

[Mvfilter](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SCS/current/SearchReference/MultivalueEvalFunctions#mvfilter.28.26lt.3Bpredicate.26gt.3B.29): Eg: `mvfilter(eval(x!=userId))`

Or created a new mvfield with the userId removed by it's index in the mvfield using this: [Add/Edit/Delete mvfield](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/How-do-you-change-one-value-in-a-multivalue-field/m-p/502906)

Instead of removing you could also choose to replace the UserId with "{userId}", so long as you do the same for all Urls.

And then you can rejoin the url using `mvjoin(url,"/")`

I hope I understood your question correctly and this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a `replace()` on your URL field with [`eval`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval) before calling `stats`:

```
| eval url=replace(url,"\/\d+\/settings","/settings")
```

If it turns out the userid is important to hold onto, pull it into its own field prior to running `replace()`:

```
| rex field=url "\/(?<userid>\d+)\/settings"
```

#### expansion for comment

For multiple possible endings of your URL, try something like this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp URL IN("*/api/v1/users/*/settings","*/api/v1/users/*/logout","*/api/v1/users/*/profile")
| rex field=url "\/(?<url_type>\w+)$"
| eval url=replace(url,"\/\d+\/\w+$","")
| stats avg(timeTaken) as avg_latency, p99(timeTaken) as "p99(ms)", perc75(timeTaken) as "p75(ms)", count  as total_requests, count(eval(responseStatus=500)) as failed_requests by url type
| eval "success_rate"=round((total_requests - failed_requests)/total_requests*100,2) 
| eval avg = round(avg) 
| sort success_rate
```

This will extract the "type" (logout, profile, settings) into a new field, then cleanup the URL by removing everything from userid to the end

Comment: It worked. Just about a little improvement. What if I also have 2 more endpoints? `/api/v1/users/{userId}/profile`, `/api/v1/users/{userId}/logout`. How can I include these urls into the table, so I have the list of these three endpoints?

Comment: @red_fox - see update